# Android Emulator Scroll Down Doesn't Work in Home Page

Tags: android, kotlin, scroll, emulation

I am new in Android Studio. I am using Android Emulator for call rest API for my backend. Before, i scroll down basicly in main android page. But after i wanted to tried scroll down, as if i right clicked, Home Setting, Widgets and Wallpaper pop-up show me. What is the solution about that. I never changed any setting.

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your emulator is frozen. It happens quite often.
I would suggest you to try these:

1. Restart your computer and try to run your app in the emulator. After it successfully runs, now try to clear the app cache.
2. If that didn't help, create another emulator. I recommend to choose different device and API level than the current emulator device but it is not necessary. This should solve your problem.

**Tips**
If you want to clear data, clear cache, uninstall app, clear cache and restart the app and so many such actions from android studio without touching your emulator then you can use ADB Idea plugin.
For that, in android studio go to Settings -> Plugins
search for ADB Idea in marketplace. Install it.
You need to restart android studio.
To use it:

1. You can press shift key in your keyboard twice and search for Adb in search window. You will get all the options from the plugin
2. From android studio menu... Tools -> ADB Idea and then you will see all the options available.